# Jquery what is wrong with this function

Tags: jquery, json, post

edit:
my script is called by a button: `$("#btnLogout").click(function() {  the ajax here`

i an wondering if there is something wrong with this:

```
        $.ajax({
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: {"fname":"123456"},
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      //url: "PersonService.asmx/AddPerson"
      url: "http://mark:123456@interfaces.local/users/145198/users/update"
    });
```

it seams not to work and i don't get any error so i can see what's wrong.

i want to change a record from my database with values from `data`

thanks

---

alright, 
i found my answer with `arma's` help.
the `type: "PUT",` command is for modifying something.
the `type: "POST",` command is for creating/adding something.

```
var mydata = {"fname":"bobworth"};
$.ajax({
type: "PUT",
processData : false,
data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
dataType: "json",
url: "http://www.xxx.com/users/",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
username: "mark",
password: "123456",
success: function(t){    alert(t);  },
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
alert("jqXHR:"+jqXHR.status+" txtStatus:"+textStatus+" Error:"+error);  }
});
```

thanks to everyone.

Comment: Are you using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is in `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`
Dunno what you are doing on server side but default 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is almost always what you want to use. Also content is always sent in UTF-8 so you don't need to specify that.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  data: {"fname":"123456"},
  dataType: "jsonp",
  type: "POST",
  //url: "PersonService.asmx/AddPerson"
  url: "http://mark:123456@interfaces.local/users/145198/users/update",

  success: function(t){
    alert(t);
  },

  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
    alert("jqXHR:"+jqXHR.status+" txtStatus:"+textStatus+" Error:"+error);
  }
});
```

Just echo back something and you should see if it works okey.

And for serverside (i know only php :)):

```
$output = json_encode("myresponse_or_arrays");
if(isset($_POST['callback'])){
   $final = $_POST['callback']."(".$output.")";
}
echo $final; // This without any kind of checks or w/e ofc
```

Comment: hmhm i got this working fine with 1.5.2 jquery and php. Maybe problem with url ?

Comment: when using curl the POST is working. the url is ok, i test it

Comment: Must be something funny, since i can get this sample working on all my browsers and starting from jquery 1.3.2 ( didn't even try earlier ). Btw url you try to use isn't local that you use full url string there? If so you need extra setting `crossDomain=true` ( but usually this is set by default)

Comment: do you think i can use `username: "mark"` and `password: "123456"` and `url" "/users/145198/users/update"`

Comment: ok. i see this error `Object { readyState=4, status=0, statusText="error"}`  and the alert is `[object Object]` what all this mean?

Comment: i updated my answer for error part try that and it should give more detailed info.

Comment: i get `"Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012"`. But the files are o n the same server... cannot be because of the cross domain thing, hmmmmm

Comment: I updated code up there. Change to `dataType: "jsonp"` and on server side you can then catch this by (for php example) $_POST['callback']; And then you need to send it back with your json part like set your `json_encode` part then append `$_POST['callback']` to that json string so you will end up with something like `$_POST['callback']."(".$json_string.")";`

Comment: one more thing. if i use `jsonp` i get this `jqXHR:200 txtStatus:parsererror Error:jQuery15105397176177602061_1302192404165 was not called`   ... you have an ideea of what this means?

Comment: Well textStatus:parseerror usually means some kind of typo in your serverside code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      data: { fname: "123456" },
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://mark:123456@interfaces.local/users/145198/users/update"
});
```

And make sure the `url` is on the same domain as your page

Comment: do you have the `success` property in there ?

Comment: i added one but no movement, it's totally dead

Comment: yes, it's on the same server.. the problem is that i can't see what is the problem

Comment: do you actually see the request being fired? like in the console? maybe something is breaking before even getting to this call

Answer (score 0):

- how are you calling this $.ajax method? maybe you're just not calling it?
- i assume interfaces.local is a hosts file entry pointing to your local machine?

arma's post looks pretty good, are you getting javascript errors? what browser are you using and what OS?

use firebug or chromes dom inpsector and throw some console.log() entries before it gets called and after, so you can at least know that it hit that piece of code?

Comment: i am calling the script with a button `$("#save").click(function() { ajax here`. the `url` is on one computer next to me, i am using it as a temporary server. firebug doesnt show any js errors and it doesnt show POST's. I must be the last person who has this kind of problem

Answer (score -1):

Change :

```
data: {"fname":"123456"},
```

To

```
data: {fname:"123456"},
```